# crash log: InternalError in MediaPlayer.setSubtitleAnchor

Tags: java, android, crash-reports

Seeing the following crash log pop up quite often:

```
java.lang.InternalError: 
  at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate (Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.start (Thread.java:733)
  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setSubtitleAnchor (MediaPlayer.java:3039)
  at android.media.MediaPlayer.scanInternalSubtitleTracks (MediaPlayer.java:3240)
  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare (MediaPlayer.java:1442)
  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create (MediaPlayer.java:1046)
  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create (MediaPlayer.java:1012)
  ...
```

I call `MediaPlayer.create` with the context/resource parameters. It works fine for me and for 95% of users. One thing to note is that I do get the dreaded

```
 E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
```

log message which is the topic of many, many StackOverflow questions. I currently have been ignoring it like most answers tell me to - but if `scanInternalSubtitleTracks` is creating InternalError crashes, maybe I shouldn't?

Comment: Actually it should be a warning, as the mediaplayer always look for any subtitles, attached to media while playing and if none exists, it throw an internal error. You can verify this behavior by playing a media file (audio/video) with subtitles or attaching a dummy subtitle to your file.

Comment: I would have expected only a warning, too, but this stack trace shows up under my Android app's logged "crashes" in the Play Console. My files are audio only...but I'll try and add an dummy subtitle.

Answer (score 4):

in the media Player android after MEDIA_PREPARED, Player start search subtitle and any Exception happen during searching subtitle send instead of crashing.
you should ignore it or you can use another player like ExoPlayer.

```
case MEDIA_PREPARED:
    try {
         scanInternalSubtitleTracks();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      // send error message instead of crashing;
      // send error message instead of inlining a call to onError
      // to avoid code duplication.
      Message msg2 = obtainMessage(
                        MEDIA_ERROR, MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN, MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED, null);
      sendMessage(msg2);
    }
    OnPreparedListener onPreparedListener = mOnPreparedListener;
    if (onPreparedListener != null)
         onPreparedListener.onPrepared(mMediaPlayer);
         return;
```

in android version 28 android let you use `.setOnSubtitleDataListener()` that could solve your problem on android 28

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that even though this Exception shows up under Play Console's "crash logs", this didn't actually lead to a crash on the customers' devices?

Comment: yes that's true.
that's handle by android and just send as crash to your carshlytic.

Comment: Hmm, according to this page https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/crash it should only count as a "crash" if Android made the app stop. Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: no your not, but that did n`t crash.android handle exception as RuntimeException and return message to you.
I add that part of code to answer